# Bing Maps SDK Windows Phone 8.1 Tile Opacity

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, bing-maps

I want to be able to set the Opacity of the Tile layer that I am rendering on top of a Bing Maps control in Windows Phone 8.1.

I am currently using the HttpMapTileDataSource object to get my tile data from a remote server. However, neither this or the MapTileSource object has an opacity property.

I know Bing Maps for WP 8.1 tries to eliminate the need for opacity by setting the appropriate MapTileLayer enum. However, I need to be able to allow a user to set the opacity on the tile images according to their preference.

Here is a little code snippet of where I am implementing the data source and adding the tiles to the map:

```
            HttpMapTileDataSource dataSource = new HttpMapTileDataSource(baseUrl);
            dataSource.AllowCaching = true;

            var customTileSource = new MapTileSource(dataSource);

            customTileSource.IsFadingEnabled = false;
            customTileSource.AllowOverstretch = true;
            customTileSource.Layer = MapTileLayer.AreaOverlay;
            customTileSource.Visible = visible;
            customTileSource.IsRetryEnabled = true;
            customTileSource.IsTransparencyEnabled = true;
            tileSources.Add(customTileSource);

            // adding the source to my map control
            _map.TileSources.Add(customTileSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

WP8.1 map tile layers do not support opacity on their own. However you can add it by using a custom tile source. I have a code sample of how to do this here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Adding-Opacity-and-WMS-cf6773f1

Comment: I have downloaded this source in the past, but I recall it having certain limitations that weren't ideal for me. One thing that HttpMapTileDataSource does is continually poll the remote URI when zooming in and out and panning. Does your solution allow for that?

Comment: I don't believe any of the tile layers do that. The tile data sources automatically cache the data for performance reasons. If the caching didn't happen your app would likely be really slow on a mobile device. You could always remove and re-add the data source after a period of time to force an update.